# HTML form only works in Chrome after browser refresh

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I'm working on an existing Rails application using Turbolinks.

I have a plans page with upgrade/downgrade functionality. When this page is visited from another page and a button is clicked to upgrade nothing happens, although when I refresh my browser it seems to work fine and posts the form.

The strange thing is that other buttons work fine with Turbolinks installed and it only seems to happen in Chrome. Firefox, Opera and Safari it works fine.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I've searched through Google all morning but can't seem to find a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a problem with Google Chrome. I've fixed it by putting the attribute `data-no-turbolink` in the HTML on the link that goes to the page in question.

Now, when I go to the page via clicking on the link it doesn't use Turbolinks and makes a full refresh of the page.

To just target Chrome (as it seems to work in other browsers) you could use this piece of js:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
     $("your-css-selector").attr('data-no-turbolink', true);
}
```

Could be seen as a bit of a hack, but it works.